# KeyError reading a JSON file

Tags: json, django, webhooks

EDIT: Here's a bit more context to how the JSON is received. I'm using the ApiAI API to generate a request to their platform, and they have a method to retrieve it, like this:

```
# instantiate ApiAI
ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)

# declare a request obect, fill in in lower lines
request = ai.text_request()

# send ApiAI the request
request.query = "{}".format(textobject.body)

# get response from ApiAI
response = request.getresponse()
response_decode = response.read().decode("utf-8")
response_data = json.loads(response_decode)
```

---

I'm coding a webapp in Django and trying to read through a JSON response POSTed to a webhook. The code to read through the JSON, after it has been decoded, is:

```
if response_data['result']['action'] != "":
    Request.objects.create(
        request = response_data['result']['resolvedQuery']
    )
```

When I try to run this code, I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'result'
```

on the line

```
if response_data['result']['action'] != "":
```

I'm confused because it looks to me like `'result'` should be a valid key to this JSON that is being read:

```
{  
   'id':'65738806-eb8b-4c9a-929f-28dc09d6a333',
   'timestamp':'2017-07-10T04:59:46.345Z',
   'lang':'en',
   'result':{  
      'source':'agent',
      'resolvedQuery':'Foobar',
      'action':'Baz'
   },
   'alternateResult':{  
      'source':'domains',
      'resolvedQuery':'abcdef',
      'actionIncomplete':False,
   },
   'status':{  
      'code':200,
      'errorType':'success'
   }
}
```

Is there another way I should be reading this JSON in my program?

Comment: Need more context, please post the code prior to the problem line, including how the response is serialized from JSON to python objects.

Comment: That's not the json that is being loaded, I'm sure you're not loading it properly, have you done json.loads??

Comment: Yes, I used `json.loads` after decoding the response into utf-8. From there, I am trying to access elements within it just like I would with normal json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import JSON
if 'action' in response_data:
    parsed_data = json.loads(response_data)
    if parsed_data['result']['action'] != "":
        Request.objects.create(request = parsed_data['result']['resolvedQuery'])
```

Comment: Hi, I already had something similar in my code. I edited my post to give some more context -- I have imported JSON, decoded the response, and ran it through json.loads.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's thoughts. It turned out there was an another error with how I was trying to implement the ApiAI API, and that was causing this error. It now reads through the JSON fine, and I'm using @sasuke's suggestion.